# IBM Integration Toolkit : Not able to access elements & assign default namespace

Tags: xml, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have spent three days researching and probing different ways to access root element of XML message at input node, but not able to get not null result from this operation:

```
DECLARE RootElement CHARACTER FIELDNAME(InputRoot.XMLNSC.*[<]);
```

RootElement is always null, but when I do (below), message is properly copied.

```
SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
```

The thing is that incoming message does not have any namespaces declared, and in compute node, I am trying to assign it:

```
SET OutputRoot.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns = orgs_crm;
```

where, **orgs_crm** is

```
DECLARE NS_CRM_MDO CONSTANT CHARACTER 'http://example.org/schema_crm';
DECLARE orgs_crm    NAMESPACE   NS_CRM_MDO;
```

Input message is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message><MessageId>5348569534564534682</MessageId></Message>
```

Output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmlns="http://example.org/schema_crm" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <MessageId>5348569534564534682</MessageId>
</Message>
```

I am sad that there is not enough information about IBM's Integration Toolkit development. Even with the RedBook ([here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247137.pdf)), I was not able to understand how to make things work. I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an answer to this question. I had to first convert incoming `InputRoot.BLOB` to `XMLNSC` in preceding compute node, only then I could do usual XML transformations.

```
DECLARE inCCSID INT InputProperties.CodedCharSetId; 
DECLARE inEncoding INT InputProperties.Encoding; 
DECLARE inBitStream BLOB ASBITSTREAM(InputRoot.BLOB, inEncoding, inCCSID); 
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN('XMLNSC') PARSE(inBitStream, inEncoding, inCCSID,'BLOB', 'XMLNSC');
```